# Top Alignment in Tabular*

Tags: tables, tabulary

I have searched for how to do this for an incredible number of hours, checking documentation, other answers, Wiki pages, and I am just plain confused.

I am editing a nifty resume template I found online, but I am having trouble top aligning elements in a table. Here is what it currently looks like:

[image: current skills section]

If I were to have a single line of text (as in the Programming section), it aligns just fine. But once more is there, it has this funny alignment (Lab Techniques). How do I make it so "Lab Techniques" lines up with "Gel electrophoresis"?

Here is a .tex file:

```
% Important note:
% This template must be compiled with XeLaTeX, the below lines will ensure this
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{minimal} % A4 paper size by default, use 'letterpaper' for US letter

\geometry{left=2cm, top=1.5cm, right=2cm, bottom=2cm, footskip=.5cm} % Configure page margins with geometry

\fontdir[fonts/] % Specify the location of the included fonts

% Color for highlights
\colorlet{awesome}{awesome-darknight} % Default colors include: awesome-emerald, awesome-skyblue, awesome-red, awesome-pink, awesome-orange, awesome-nephritis, awesome-concrete, awesome-darknight
\definecolor{awesome}{HTML}{000000} % Uncomment if you would like to specify your own color

%Colors for text - uncomment and modify
\definecolor{darktext}{HTML}{000000}
\definecolor{text}{HTML}{000000}
\definecolor{graytext}{HTML}{000000}
\definecolor{lighttext}{HTML}{000000}


\begin{document}

\input{cv-sections/skills.tex}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

Here is the skills.tex file:

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SECTION TITLE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\cvsection{Skills}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SECTION CONTENT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{cvskills}

%------------------------------------------------

\cvskill
{Programming} % Category
{Python, C/C++, Java } % Skills

%------------------------------------------------



\cvskill
{Lab Techniques}
{Gel electrophoresis, PCR, primer design, restriction digestion, DNA ligation, Golden Gate assembly, Gibson assembly, genomic and plasmid purification, DNA quantification, SDS-PAGE, western blotting, cell transformation, batch-fed fermentation, HPLC, directed evolution, FRET, fluorescence microscopy}
%------------------------------------------------



\end{cvskills}
```

And here is the .cls file, the relevant parts (I think) are at the bottom:

```
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                Identification
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\ProvidesClass{awesome-cv}[2015/12/14 v1.3 Awesome Curriculum Vitae Class]
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                Class options
%
% (need to be done before the external package loading, for example because
% we need \paperwidth, \paperheight and \@ptsize to be defined before loading
% geometry and fancyhdr)
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Options for draft or final
\DeclareOption{draft}{\setlength\overfullrule{5pt}}
\DeclareOption{final}{\setlength\overfullrule{0pt}}
% Inherit options of article
\DeclareOption*{%
  \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}
}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{article}


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                3rd party packages
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Needed to make fixed length table
\RequirePackage{array}
% Needed to handle list environment
\RequirePackage{enumitem}
% Needed to handle text alignment
\RequirePackage{ragged2e}
% Needed to configure page layout
\RequirePackage{geometry}
% Needed to make header & footer effeciently
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
% Needed to manage colors
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
% Needed to use \ifxetex-\else-\fi statement
\RequirePackage{ifxetex}
% Needed to use \if-\then-\else statement
\RequirePackage{xifthen}
% Needed to use a toolbox of programming tools
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
% Needed to change line spacing in specific environment
\RequirePackage{setspace}
% Needed to manage fonts
\RequirePackage[quiet]{fontspec}
% To support LaTeX quoting style
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
% Needed to manage math fonts
\RequirePackage[math-style=TeX,vargreek-shape=unicode]{unicode-math}
% Needed to use icons from font-awesome
% (https://github.com/posquit0/latex-fontawesome)
\RequirePackage{fontawesome}
% Needed to deal a paragraphs
\RequirePackage{parskip}
% Needed to deal hyperlink
\RequirePackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{%
  pdftitle={},
  pdfauthor={},
  pdfsubject={},
  pdfkeywords={}
}


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                Configuration for directory locations
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Configure a directory location for fonts(default: 'fonts/')
\newcommand*{\fontdir}[1][fonts/]{\def\@fontdir{#1}}
\fontdir


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                Configuration for layout
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Page Layout
% Configure page margins with geometry
\geometry{left=2.0cm, top=1.5cm, right=2.0cm, bottom=2.0cm, footskip=.5cm}

%% Header & Footer
% Set offset to each header and footer
\fancyhfoffset{0em}
% Remove head rule
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
% Clear all header & footer fields
\fancyhf{}
% Enable if you want to make header or footer using fancyhdr
\pagestyle{fancy}


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                Configuration for colors
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Gray-scale colors
\definecolor{white}{HTML}{FFFFFF}
\definecolor{black}{HTML}{000000}
\definecolor{darkgray}{HTML}{333333}
\definecolor{gray}{HTML}{5D5D5D}
\definecolor{lightgray}{HTML}{999999}
% Basic colors
\definecolor{green}{HTML}{C2E15F}
\definecolor{orange}{HTML}{FDA333}
\definecolor{purple}{HTML}{D3A4F9}
\definecolor{red}{HTML}{FB4485}
\definecolor{blue}{HTML}{6CE0F1}
% Text colors
\definecolor{darktext}{HTML}{414141}
\colorlet{text}{darkgray}
\colorlet{graytext}{gray}
\colorlet{lighttext}{lightgray}
% Awesome colors
\definecolor{awesome-emerald}{HTML}{00A388}
\definecolor{awesome-skyblue}{HTML}{0395DE}
\definecolor{awesome-red}{HTML}{DC3522}
\definecolor{awesome-pink}{HTML}{EF4089}
\definecolor{awesome-orange}{HTML}{FF6138}
\definecolor{awesome-nephritis}{HTML}{27AE60}
\definecolor{awesome-concrete}{HTML}{95A5A6}
\definecolor{awesome-darknight}{HTML}{131A28}
\colorlet{awesome}{awesome-red}

% Awesome section color
\newcounter{colorCounter}
\def\@sectioncolor#1#2#3{%
  {%
    \color{%
      \ifcase\value{colorCounter}%
        awesome\or%
        awesome\or%
        awesome\or%
        awesome\or%
        awesome\else%
        awesome\fi%
    } #1#2#3%
  }%
  \stepcounter{colorCounter}%
}


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                Configuration for fonts
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Set font for header (default is Roboto)
\newfontfamily\headerfont[
  Path=\@fontdir,
  UprightFont=*-Regular,
  ItalicFont=*-Italic,
  BoldFont=*-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic,
]{Roboto}

\newfontfamily\headerfontlight[
  Path=\@fontdir,
  UprightFont=*-Thin,
  ItalicFont=*-ThinItalic,
  BoldFont=*-Medium,
  BoldItalicFont=*-MediumItalic,
]{Roboto}

% Set font for footer (default is Source Sans Pro)
\newfontfamily\footerfont[
  Path=\@fontdir,
  UprightFont=*-Regular,
  ItalicFont=*-It,
  BoldFont=*-Bold
]{SourceSansPro}

% Set font for body (default is Source Sans Pro)
\newfontfamily\bodyfont[
  Path=\@fontdir,
  UprightFont=*-Regular,
  ItalicFont=*-It,
  BoldFont=*-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont=*-BoldIt
]{SourceSansPro}

\newfontfamily\bodyfontlight[
  Path=\@fontdir,
  UprightFont=*-Light,
  ItalicFont=*-LightIt,
  BoldFont=*-Semibold,
  BoldItalicFont=*-SemiboldIt
]{SourceSansPro}


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                Configuration for styles
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Configure styles for each CV elements
% For fundamental structures
\newcommand*{\headerfirstnamestyle}[1]{{\fontsize{32pt}{1em}\headerfontlight\color{black} #1}}
\newcommand*{\headerlastnamestyle}[1]{{\fontsize{32pt}{1em}\headerfont\bfseries\color{black} #1}}
\newcommand*{\headerpositionstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{7.6pt}{1em}\bodyfont\scshape\color{black} #1}}
\newcommand*{\headeraddressstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{8pt}{1em}\headerfont\itshape\color{black} #1}}
\newcommand*{\headersocialstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{6.8pt}{1em}\headerfont\color{black} #1}}
\newcommand*{\headerquotestyle}[1]{{\fontsize{9pt}{1em}\bodyfont\itshape\color{black} #1}}
\newcommand*{\footerstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{8pt}{1em}\footerfont\scshape\color{black} #1}}
\newcommand*{\sectionstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{16pt}{1em}\bodyfont\bfseries\color{black}\@sectioncolor #1}}
\newcommand*{\subsectionstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{12pt}{1em}\bodyfont\scshape\textcolor{black}{#1}}}
\newcommand*{\paragraphstyle}{\fontsize{9pt}{1em}\bodyfont\upshape\color{black}}

% For elements of entry
\newcommand*{\entrytitlestyle}[1]{{\fontsize{10pt}{1em}\bodyfont\bfseries\color{black} #1}}
\newcommand*{\entrypositionstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{10pt}{1em}\bodyfont\scshape\color{black} #1}}
\newcommand*{\entrydatestyle}[1]{{\fontsize{8pt}{1em}\bodyfont\slshape\color{black} #1}}
\newcommand*{\entrylocationstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{9pt}{1em}\bodyfont\slshape\color{black} #1}}
\newcommand*{\descriptionstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{9pt}{1em}\bodyfont\upshape\color{black} #1}}

% For elements of subentry
\newcommand*{\subentrytitlestyle}[1]{{\fontsize{8pt}{1em}\bodyfont\mdseries\color{black} #1}}
\newcommand*{\subentrypositionstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{7pt}{1em}\bodyfont\scshape\color{black} #1}}
\newcommand*{\subentrydatestyle}[1]{{\fontsize{7pt}{1em}\bodyfont\slshape\color{black} #1}}
\newcommand*{\subentrylocationstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{7pt}{1em}\bodyfont\slshape\color{black} #1}}
\newcommand*{\subdescriptionstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{8pt}{1em}\bodyfont\upshape\color{black} #1}}

% For elements of honor
\newcommand*{\honortitlestyle}[1]{{\fontsize{9pt}{1em}\bodyfont\color{black} #1}}
\newcommand*{\honorpositionstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{9pt}{1em}\bodyfont\bfseries\color{black} #1}}
\newcommand*{\honordatestyle}[1]{{\fontsize{9pt}{1em}\bodyfont\color{black} #1}}
\newcommand*{\honorlocationstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{9pt}{1em}\bodyfont\slshape\color{black} #1}}

% For elements of skill
\newcommand*{\skilltypestyle}[1]{{\fontsize{10pt}{1em}\bodyfont\bfseries\color{black} #1}}
\newcommand*{\skillsetstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{9pt}{1em}\bodyfont\color{black} #1}}

% For elements of the cover letter
\newcommand*{\lettersectionstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{14pt}{1em}\bodyfont\bfseries\color{text}\@sectioncolor #1}}
\newcommand*{\recipientaddressstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{9pt}{1em}\bodyfont\scshape\color{black} #1}}
\newcommand*{\recipienttitlestyle}[1]{{\fontsize{11pt}{1em}\bodyfont\bfseries\color{black} #1}}
\newcommand*{\lettertitlestyle}[1]{{\fontsize{10pt}{1em}\bodyfont\bfseries\color{black} \underline{#1}}}
\newcommand*{\letterdatestyle}[1]{{\fontsize{9pt}{1em}\bodyfont\slshape\color{black} #1}}
\newcommand*{\lettertextstyle}{\fontsize{10pt}{1.4em}\bodyfont\upshape\color{black}}
\newcommand*{\letternamestyle}[1]{{\fontsize{10pt}{1em}\bodyfont\bfseries\color{black} #1}}
\newcommand*{\letterenclosurestyle}[1]{{\fontsize{10pt}{1em}\bodyfont\slshape\color{black} #1}}


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                Commands for personal information
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Define writer's name
% Usage: \name{<firstname>}{<lastname>}
% Usage: \firstname{<firstname>}
% Usage: \lastname{<lastname>}
% Usage: \familyname{<familyname>}
\newcommand*{\name}[2]{\def\@firstname{#1}\def\@lastname{#2}}
\newcommand*{\firstname}[1]{\def\@firstname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\lastname}[1]{\def\@lastname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\familyname}[1]{\def\@lastname{#1}}
\def\@familyname{\@lastname}

% Define writer's address
% Usage: \address{<address>}
\newcommand*{\address}[1]{\def\@address{#1}}

% Define writer's position
% Usage: \name{<position>}
\newcommand*{\position}[1]{\def\@position{#1}}

% Defines writer's mobile (optional)
% Usage: \mobile{<mobile number>}
\newcommand*{\mobile}[1]{\def\@mobile{#1}}

% Defines writer's email (optional)
% Usage: \email{<email adress>}
\newcommand*{\email}[1]{\def\@email{#1}}

% Defines writer's homepage (optional)
% Usage: \homepage{<url>}
\newcommand*{\homepage}[1]{\def\@homepage{#1}}

% Defines writer's github (optional)
% Usage: \github{<github-nick>}
\newcommand*{\github}[1]{\def\@github{#1}}

% Defines writer's linked-in (optional)
% Usage: \linkedin{<linked-in-nick>}
\newcommand*{\linkedin}[1]{\def\@linkedin{#1}}

% Defines writer's stackoverflow profile (optional)
% Usage: \stackoverflow{<so userid>}{<so username>}
%   e.g.https://stackoverflow.com/users/123456/sam-smith
%       would be \stackoverflow{123456}{sam-smith}
\newcommand*{\stackoverflow}[2]{\def\@stackoverflowid{#1}\def\@stackoverflowname{#2}}

% Defines writer's skype (optional)
% Usage: \skype{<skype account>}
\newcommand*{\skype}[1]{\def\@skype{#1}}

% Defines writer's twitter (optional)
% Usage: \twitter{<twitter handle>}
\newcommand*{\twitter}[1]{\def\@twitter{#1}}

% Defines writer's quote (optional)
% Usage: \quote{<quote>}
\renewcommand*{\quote}[1]{\def\@quote{#1}}

% Defines recipient's information (cover letter only)
% Usage: \recipient{<recipient name>}{<recipient address>}
% Usage: \recipientname{<recipient name>}
% Usage: \recipientaddress{<recipient address>}
\newcommand*{\recipient}[2]{\def\@recipientname{#1}\def\@recipientaddress{#2}}
\newcommand*{\recipientname}[1]{\def\@recipientname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\recipientaddress}[1]{\def\@recipientaddress{#1}}

% Defines the title for letter (cover letter only, optional)
% Usage: \lettertitle{<title>}
\newcommand*{\lettertitle}[1]{\def\@lettertitle{#1}}

% Defines the date for letter (cover letter only)
% Usage: \letterdate{<date>}
\newcommand*{\letterdate}[1]{\def\@letterdate{#1}}

% Defines a message of opening for letter (cover letter only)
% Usage: \letteropening{<message>}
\newcommand*{\letteropening}[1]{\def\@letteropening{#1}}

% Defines a message of closing for letter (cover letter only)
% Usage: \letterclosing{<message>}
\newcommand*{\letterclosing}[1]{\def\@letterclosing{#1}}

% Defines an enclosure for letter (cover letter only, optional)
% Usage: \letterenclosure[<enclosure name>]{<enclosure>}
\newcommand*{\letterenclname}[1][Enclosure]{\def\@letterenclname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\letterenclosure}[2][]{%
  % if an optional argument is provided, use it to redefine \enclname
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{}{\def\@letterenclname{#1}}
  \def\@letterenclosure{#2}
}


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                Commands for extra
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Define helper macros a user can change easily in header
\newcommand{\acvHeaderNameDelim}{\space}
\newcommand{\acvHeaderAfterNameSkip}{.4mm}
\newcommand{\acvHeaderAfterPositionSkip}{.4mm}
\newcommand{\acvHeaderAfterAddressSkip}{-.5mm}
\newcommand{\acvHeaderIconSep}{\space}
\newcommand{\acvHeaderSocialSep}{\quad\textbar\quad}
\newcommand{\acvHeaderAfterSocialSkip}{6mm}
\newcommand{\acvHeaderAfterQuoteSkip}{5mm}

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                Commands for utilities
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Use to align an element of tabular table
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

% Use to draw horizontal line with specific thickness
\def\vhrulefill#1{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule\@height#1\hfill \kern\z@}

% Use to execute conditional statements by checking empty string
\newcommand*{\ifempty}[3]{\ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}{#2}{#3}}


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                Commands for elements of CV structure
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Define a section for CV
% Usage: \cvsection{<section-title>}
\newcommand{\cvsection}[1]{%
  \par\addvspace{1.5ex}
  \phantomsection{}
  \sectionstyle{#1}
  \color{gray}\vhrulefill{0.9pt}
  \par\nobreak\addvspace{1ex}
}

% Define a subsection for CV
% Usage: \cvsubsection{<subsection-title>}
\newcommand{\cvsubsection}[1]{%
  \phantomsection{}
  \subsectionstyle{#1}
}

% Define a paragraph for CV
\newenvironment{cvparagraph}{%
  \vspace{-3mm}
  \paragraphstyle
}{%
  \vspace{1mm}
}


% Define an environment for cventry
\newenvironment{cventries}{%
  \begin{center}
}{%
  \end{center}
}
% Define an entry of cv information
% Usage: \cventry{<position>}{<title>}{<location>}{<date>}{<description>}
\newcommand*{\cventry}[5]{%
  \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
  \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} L{\textwidth - 4.5cm} R{4.5cm}}
    \ifempty{#2#3}
      {\entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
      {\entrytitlestyle{#2} & \entrylocationstyle{#3} \\
      \entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
    \multicolumn{2}{L{\textwidth}}{\descriptionstyle{#5}} \\
  \end{tabular*}
}

% Define an environment for cvsubentry
\newenvironment{cvsubentries}{%
  \begin{center}
}{%
  \end{center}
}
% Define a subentry of cv information
% Usage: \cvsubentry{<position>}{<title>}{<date>}{<description>}
\newcommand*{\cvsubentry}[4]{%
  \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
  \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} L{\textwidth - 4.5cm} R{4.5cm}}
    \setlength\leftskip{0.2cm}
    \subentrytitlestyle{#2} & \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}
      {\subentrydatestyle{#3}}{} 
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}
      {}
      {\subentrypositionstyle{#1} & \subentrydatestyle{#3} \\}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}
      {}
      {\multicolumn{2}{L{17.0cm}}{\subdescriptionstyle{#4}} \\}
  \end{tabular*}
}

% Define an environment for cvhonor
\newenvironment{cvhonors}{%
  \begin{center}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} C{1.5cm} L{\textwidth - 4.0cm} R{2.5cm}}
}{%
    \end{tabular*}
  \end{center}
}
% Define a line of cv information(honor, award or something else)
% Usage: \cvhonor{<position>}{<title>}{<location>}{<date>}
\newcommand*{\cvhonor}[4]{%
  \honordatestyle{#4} & \honorpositionstyle{#1}, \honortitlestyle{#2} & \honorlocationstyle{#3} \\
}

% Define an environment for cvskill
\newenvironment{cvskills}{%
  \begin{center}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{1ex}
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0ex}
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} r L{\textwidth * \real{0.85}} }
}{%
    \end{tabular*}
  \end{center}
}


% Define a line of cv information(skill)
% Usage: \cvskill{<type>}{<skillset>}
\newcommand*{\cvskill}[2]{%
    \skilltypestyle{#1} & \skillsetstyle{#2} \\
}
```

I guess first - Wikibooks tells me the "L" parameter is for the Tabulary environment, but it seems to be used here with tabular*, why? (I control+F'd "tabulary" in the .cls file, nothing came up)

From my understanding, the alignment is being taken care of by the "r" (right justified) and the L (left justified). I tried using [t] but perhaps I am just not doing it right.

Help would be incredibly appreciated.

EDIT: I have put up the full Latex code that will generate the problem I have. In line 459, at the bottom, it says:

```
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} r L{\textwidth * \real{0.85}} }
```

And a commenter suggested I try replacing "L" with "p" -- this gets me somewhat closer, but it seems to align with the bottom of the text instead of the top:

```
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} r p{\textwidth * \real{0.85}} }
```

[image: after p]

Comment: Welcome to the site! It would be great if you could turn your snippet into a complete, minimal working example -- it really helps those that might be able to help :)

Comment: alright, lemme copy paste the entire .cls and .tex file

Comment: you have not shown the definition of `L` but I assume it is `m` (vertically centered) rather than `p` (top) aligned.  The alignment shown isn't `funny` it just has the baseline of the first column aligned with the vertical centre of the second, which is what you would get from `{l m{3cm}}`

Comment: Working example is up!

Also @DavidCarlisle, I am not entirely sure what you mean by the definition of L, although I pasted the whole code to generate my problem if that helps. I tried using "p" instead of L, but it doesn't top align like I expected. Picture is above.

Thank you guys so far for your help

Answer (score 2):

You have

```
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
```

which specifies that `L` columns have the reference point in their centre, if the definition was

```
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
```

the reference point would be on the baseline of the first line.

You also need to fix

```
\newcommand*{\skillsetstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{9pt}{1em}\bodyfont\color{black} #1}}
```

to

```
\newcommand*{\skillsetstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{9pt}{1em}\bodyfont\leavevmode\color{black} #1}}
```

In general it is much simpler to start with an understandable template such as standard `article` class and add what is needed, than start with a large and only partially documented set of code and have to try to debug and fix it.

Comment: ahh thank you so much! I upvoted you but because I have <15 reputation it doesn't show up.

And good advice, even though this problem is fixed, I anticipate more will pop up -- I'll start from a simple template and add things from there. Again - thank you!

Edit: Wait, can you elaborate on leavevmode? Is vertical mode the default for tables in Tex?

Comment: @AruSingh vertical mode is what the latex manual calls par-mode, so it is the mode used for anything that takes pargraphs of text eg `p` and `m` columns, `\parbox` and the main text body